# Given an undirected graph and a path, find the longest extended path

Tags: python, graph-theory

I would like to write an efficient program (ideally in Python) that, given an adjacency matrix for an undirected graph and an ordered list of vertices (i.e. a path), finds the longest path that contains the ordered list. I guess a very basic way to do this would be to iterate on the start and end vertices in the list and find all extended paths, then take the longest one. This seems quite inefficient to me, however - are there any improvements to this idea?

Edit: by 'path' I mean that each vertex appears at most once in the path.

Comment: Wait. This is an *undirected acyclic* graph? As in, a forest? There is at most one path between any two nodes in a forest.

Comment: Apologies, on second thoughts the graph need not be acyclic. Thanks for the comment, will update the question.

Comment: That's much harder, then - in fact, it's NP-hard, by straightforward reduction from the Hamiltonian path problem.

Answer (score 0):

If an undirected graph is acyclic, then each connected part is a tree, and finding the longest path is easy by DFS or BFS. If an undirected graph has cycles, then there is no longest path, because you can go around a cycle again and again ad infinitum. If instead you want to find the longest shortest path to any vertex, then you can use BFS

Comment: "longest shortest path"? What?

Comment: @user2357112 For a graph then for all pairs of vertices where there exists at least one path between those vertices then there exists a shortest path between those vertices and you can compose a set of all such shortest paths and one-or-more of those paths must be the longest within that set and that would be the longest shortest-path.